# Can I receive the error message "error_not_register" from gcm server even if I didn't uninstall the app?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I receive the error message `error_not_register` from GCM server even if I didn't uninstall the App.

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here are the cases in which you can receive the `NotRegistered` error :

> **Unregistered Device**
>
> An existing registration ID may cease to be valid in a number of scenarios, including:
>
> - If the application manually unregisters by issuing a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER intent.
> - If the application is automatically unregistered, which can happen (but is not guaranteed) if the user uninstalls the application.
> - If the registration ID expires. Google might decide to refresh registration IDs.
> - If the application is updated but the new version does not have a broadcast receiver configured to receive com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE intents.
>
> For all these cases, you should remove this registration ID from the 3rd-party server and stop using it to send messages.
>   Happens when error code is NotRegistered.

Since you supplied no code and very little information, it's hard to say which of them applies to your case.

Comment: I have been GCM servicing. But when i send a message to some devices my 3'rd party server receive that error message even if user didn't uninstall App... It has not happening all devices...